# How Can I fix error in Expo CLI after starting?

Tags: javascript, react-native, cryptocurrency

I"m forking from turtle-coin wallet and I want run expo client. However, after i do in cli `expo start`, localhost launches website, builds JavaScript, etc., but there's an error there:

```
{"type":"client_log","level":"warn","data":["Require cycle: node_modules\\react-native-crypto\\index.js -> node_modules\\react-native-randombytes\\index.js -> node_modules\\sjcl\\sjcl.js -> node_modules\\react-native-crypto\\index.js\n\nRequire cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle."]}.
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs because the imports that you've made in your files have somehow created a cyclic dependency. Please `check and verify all your imports carefully` and you'll be good go!

Comment: How can check them ? Because there are lot of node modules , i found directories of this that was written in error code but what now hm

Comment: You need not check `node_modules`, just check your app files and their respective imports!